# how can i change CSS using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I want to when I click on the right-top raindrop, the others rotate but I don't know anything about javascript and jquery! I know css!

This is my javascript code until now:

```
$(function() {
    $('#left').click(function() {
        $(this).css('width', '200px');
    });
}):
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hamidrezabstn/hGTFa/)

Comment: `document.getElementById("elementID").style.cssproperty = "value of css property"`

Comment: Please include the relevant code *in your question*, don't circumvent the check by pretending your link is code.

Comment: @DavidThomas i try to include my code but it keeps errors me!

Comment: You should be able to paste your code into the text, highlight it and hit the `{}` button to format code as code.

Comment: Quite unclear to me: You're asking how to change CSS with JavaScript/Jquery, but you're showing an example in your description, and then you ask how to make an animation/transition, without even showing us what you have tried to animate your element at first.

Comment: If you need help formatting your questions, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @DavidThomas i did that but it wont work

Comment: @JeffNoel yes! its simple! i want to make a css animation using javascript or jquery! when someone clicks on the right-top raindrop it rotate and with some delay other rain drops rotate !

Comment: @hamidrezabstn Then include what you have **TRIED** to achieve those effects instead of including unrelevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, include **JQuery** if you're using it.

And you have a typo in your code

```
$(function() {
      $('#left').click(function() {
            $(this).css('width', '200px');
      });
});
--^--
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGTFa/1/)

Answer (score 4):

tymeJV's comment will work. Alternatively, using jQuery you could do:

```
$('#elementId').css('propertyname','propertyvalue');
```

Comment: Hey Vucko, what did you change with my response? New to this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18279232/revisions

Comment: all you need to do is click on the 'edited x mins ago' - it will show you the edits

Comment: It looks as if he just formatted the code snippet you provided, nothing major. You can click on the link that says "edited X mins ago" to see the history of revisions.

Comment: @ParisNelson I just formatted your code so it looks better. :)

Comment: i have done this! wont work! see my live demo!

Comment: @hamidrezabstn Your live demo has errors. You didn't include jQuery. And you have a rogue `:` (instead of `;`). Working: http://jsfiddle.net/ecMEJ/

Comment: @Vucko thanks! Didn't know how to denote something as code.

Answer (score 2):

**In javascript:**

```
 document.getElementById("your_id").style.css_property = "value";
```

for example:

`document.getElementById("your_id").style.display = "block";`

**In jquery:**

```
$("#id").css("css_property","value");
```

For example:

```
 $("#id").css("display","block");
```

Comment: This is the right answer. In my case, I know how to do it with jQuery, but I'm loading jQuery with require.js and I need to perform a simple style mod before loading my async scripts. Of course, I could just load jQuery in the global namespace, but that's not elegant.